# calc(100vh - 44px) not working in TailwindCSS 3

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-3, tailwind-variants

I tried all of these:

```
<ul className="overflow-y-auto bg-surface-50 rounded-b-lg  h-[calc(100vh_-_44px)] sm:h-fit ">
<ul className="overflow-y-auto bg-surface-50 rounded-b-lg  h-[calc(100vh-44px)] sm:h-fit ">
```

But when tailwind compiles, I still see no class `h-[calc(100vh-44px)]` and also no styling.

Comment: I do plus I don't I need since I'm using version 3 right ?

Comment: Are you sure tailwind watches the file where this class is? What is the `content` section of your config file? How do you compile styles?

Comment: Your syntax looks ok, then. Must be something else that we can't see from here.

Comment: The generated class will look like this in css btw: `h-\[calc\(100vh-44px\)\]`

Comment: so I'm using it on a ```ul``` like this  ```<ul className="overflow-y-auto bg-surface-50 rounded-b-lg  h-[calc(100vh_-_44px)] sm:h-fit ">``` the weird thing is that it complies the other classes but not this one .

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out the extra space after `sm:h-fit` and before `h-[calc(100vh_-_44px)]` was the culprit. This fixed it - removing all unnecessary spaces:

```
<ul className="h-[calc(100vh_-_44px)] sm:h-fit overflow-y-auto bg-surface-50 rounded-b-lg">
```